# Moq 4.2 and Tasks fires an exception

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

since I updated to the latest version of Moq (4.2) I'm having some unit test failing.
I'm getting the System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'FilterCriteria' to type 'SortCriteria'.
As my code uses Task's to get these values I suspect the new version of Moq works differently than previous one.

This is the code in question:

In tested class:

```
Task<FilterCriteria> getFilterCriteriaTask = Task<FilterCriteria>.Factory.StartNew(() => searchService.GetFilterCriteriaFromCache(id));
Task<SortCriteria> getSortCriteriaTask = Task<SortCriteria>.Factory.StartNew(() => searchService.GetSortCriteriaFromCache(id));

FilterCriteria filterCriteria = getFilterCriteriaTask.Result;
SortCriteria sortCriteria = getSortCriteriaTask.Result;
```

In unit test:

```
searchServiceMock
   .Setup(it => it.GetFilterCriteriaFromCache(expectedCacheKey, null))
   .Returns(expectedFilterCriteria);

searchServiceMock
   .Setup(it => it.GetSortCriteriaFromCache(expectedCacheKey))
   .Returns(expectedSortCriteria);
```

Any idea on what it can be due to?
I really do not know where to start.

Thanks

Comment: Why the additional `null` argument in `it.GetFilterCriteriaFromCache(expectedCacheKey, null)`? Is that the problem?

Comment: No, the same test just worked before the update of Moq.

Comment: Btw. That was added only because that method has a parameter with a default value and for Moq it needs to be, however, specified.